# How is it possible to put value in subrecords of a struct?

Tags: julia

If it needs to put a value in a sub structure in Julia, how is it possible?
for example I have this structure

```
struct individual
    position
    cost
end

pop = [individual(rand(0:1,10),[]) for i in 1:2]
```

if position will change in code to this value `x=[0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2]`

How is it possible?

if append!() is used

```
append!(pop[1].position,x)


individual([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2], Any[])
```

but I want this

```
individual([0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2], Any[])
```

would you please help me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just empty the container before appending `x` like this:

```
append!(empty!(pop[1].position), x)
```

or define `individual` as mutable and then you can simply use assignment like this:

```
julia> mutable struct individual
           position
           cost
       end

julia> pop = [individual(rand(0:1,10),[]) for i in 1:2]
2-element Array{individual,1}:
 individual([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], Any[])
 individual([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], Any[])

julia> x=[0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2]
10-element Array{Int64,1}:
 0
 2
 0
 0
 2
 0
 0
 2
 2
 2

julia> pop[1].position = x
10-element Array{Int64,1}:
 0
 2
 0
 0
 2
 0
 0
 2
 2
 2

julia> pop
2-element Array{individual,1}:
 individual([0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2], Any[])
 individual([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], Any[])
```